# can't import pandas to jupyter lab in anaconda

Tags: pandas, anaconda

I worked on pandas last night and didn't have any problems but today I opened jupyterlab on anaconda and got this error after typing "import pandas as pd". I searched the site for a long time to solve the error, but I couldn't find the solution. how can i fix this error?

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.frame'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it using pip

```
!pip install pandas
```

Or

Try to upgrade it

```
!pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: Please see my recent comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094260/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-in-ubuntu/74094354#comment130833215_74094354) and update your suggestions to keep with best practices. Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with `pip install` or `conda install` in Jupyter is outdated. `%pip install pandas` in this case.