# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' in ubuntu

Tags: python, jupyter, torch

When I want use torch in jupyter, I got this error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

but I check that torch is installed already. following:

```
>>> python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
1.10.2+cu102
```

It is confirmed in Ubuntu CLI, but there is an error in jupyter only.

How can I fix it??

- OS : Linux(Ubuntu 18.04)
- Python : 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu CLI is not the same environment with jupyter.
In Jupyter run this command`%pip install <package name>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Answer is modified.

Comment: @jp1527 I deleted it so things are cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install torch in the current jupyter kernel.
Run within your script:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install torch
```

See [Details](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) here.